# Looking for source code for Crafter Deployer 2.5.3

Tags: crafter-cms

I have an instance of crafter running with crafter-studio-publishing-receiver-2.5.3-aio.jar, I need to locate the source code for the jar file.

Is this the right [repository](https://github.com/craftercms/legacy-deployer/tree/2.5.x)

What is the significance of the word "legacy" in the name of the project?

Comment: Do you mind changing the title of this question? "How do I locate  source code for a specific version of a Crafter CMS component (i.e. 2.5.3 Deployer)?" – Russ Danner just now   edit

Comment: The question/answer is legitimate but in its present form, may not be as helpful to others.

Changing the title and rewording the body to use the deployer and it's version as an example would help a lot!  THANKS!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the source code here:
https://github.com/craftercms/legacy-deployer

The specific version can be found by checking the manifest of the jar.
- unzip the jar
- open ./META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
- locate the property Implementation-Build: 87c84d58313b2bcbdca306de69758320aee174d0

This value can be placed in github to get the exact code you are looking for.
Example:
https://github.com/craftercms/legacy-deployer/blob/87c84d58313b2bcbdca306de69758320aee174d0/cstudio-publishing-receiver-zip/pom.xml

The reason we renamed the project "legacy-deployer" in github is that with Crafter 3.x we are moving to a new deployment system.  Without going too deep on this: The new system is based on Git pulls, as you can imagine, this approach has *many* benefits. It will support the same concepts (callbacks etc) as the now "legacy" deployer.